# SKCropNode not rendering greyscale mask values in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, mask, skcropnode

I have an SKCropNode that is working fine except for one thing - all of the greyscale values in the mask image that are not black or white are getting set to solid white.[image]

This means that all greyscale alpha values are not rendering with transparency, but are just being set to be fully opaque.

Here is my code:

```
    let foregroundTexture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("P01_foreground.jpg"))!)
    var foreground = SKSpriteNode(texture: foregroundTexture)

    let maskTexture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("P01_mask.png"))!)
    var mask = SKSpriteNode(texture: maskTexture)

    var cropNode = SKCropNode()
    cropNode.addChild(foreground)
    cropNode.maskNode = mask
    cropNode.position = CGPoint(x: device.x/2, y: device.y/2)
    cropNode.zPosition = 2.0
    self.addChild(cropNode)
```

Does anyone know why the greyscale areas are being set to white or how I can achieve the desired result? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like you can't. SKCropNode currently only has one property, the [maskNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCropNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKCropNode/maskNode) itself. There are no additional settings available to do what you want.

Comment: Yea...that's kinda what I'm thinking. :(